# How to create a Typescript function that the 2nd parameter depends on the 1st parameter?

Tags: typescript

Given the following data structure

```js
const mapA = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
}

const mapB = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
}

const maps = {
  A: mapA,
  B: mapB,
}

const func = (mapName: keyof typeof maps, prop: ?) => {
  //
}
```

How should I write the type of prop in "?" such that

```js
func('A', 'c') // = 3
func('B', 'c') // throw Typescript error
```

I have attempted the following but failed:

```
const func = <T extends keyof Maps>(mapName: T, prop: Maps[T]) => {
  const value = maps[mapName][prop];
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwA4EEYF4YG8BQMYIBcMAjADR4wBGxATBfsMQMwUC+OOoksiSAQhmyUipBtTrtO3aPGQQhufCmJ8U4-quT8pOKAE8kAUxgBZeUIPGQAMzlIIAbmnhZNgK5hgQgDwAVGCMADygjMAATBQBrI31bM3kAPgAKPgA5BDgjYj8yGCQAJxAkYnMHAG0-AF0ASgxE4UZXWAA3BAAbdxNMPghy9MyjKvLC4qrnNiA)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: By what logic should the error be thrown?  Couldn't this be done by code at the start of the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic words are mapped types and key inference.

```
const func = <T extends keyof Maps, K extends keyof Maps[T]>(mapName: T, prop: K): Maps[T][K] => {
  return maps[mapName][prop];
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=3&pln=19&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwA4EEYF4YG8BQMYIBcMAjADR4wBGxATBfsMQMwUC%20OOoksiSAQhmyUipBtTrtO3aPGQQhufCmJ8U4-quT8pOKAE8kAUxgBZeUIPGQAMzlIIAbmnhZNgK5hgQgDwAVGCMADygjMAATBQBrI31bM3kyGABpQJCwyJgYuLtzBwBtPwBdAD4ACj4AOQQ4I2I-JKQAJxAkYmSASmI8iEKi-OSijBLhfCajKHcmsHteqpqjfubWouc2ZxwPLzKAchQdpJ3gHY7HGAB6c6FmTc9gXf4DmCOTs8uYPwALFoB3BQQPoYjABlYBNACWSFgRiaLSaQA)